# How do I remove comma after last number/output loop in C++

Tags: c++

My Code:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

void result(int test) 
{   

    for (int num = 1; num <= test; num++) 
    {   
        if (num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0)
            cout << "extra";

        else if (num % 3 == 0 )
            cout << "love ";


        else if(num %5 == 0) 
            cout << "extraextra";   

        else 
            cout << num;
        cout << ",";
    }
}


int main() 
{  
    int test = 100; 
    result(test); 

    return 0; 
}
```

My Output:

```
1,2,love ,4,extraextra,love ,7,8,love ,extraextra,11,love ,13,14,extra,16,17,love ,19,extraextra,love ,22,23,love ,extraextra,26,love ,28,29,extra,31,32,love ,34,extraextra,love ,37,38,love ,extraextra,41,love ,43,44,extra,46,47,love ,49,extraextra,love ,52,53,love ,extraextra,56,love ,58,59,extra,61,62,love ,64,extraextra,love ,67,68,love ,extraextra,71,love ,73,74,extra,76,77,love ,79,extraextra,love ,82,83,love ,extraextra,86,love ,88,89,extra,91,92,love ,94,extraextra,love ,97,98,love ,extraextra,
```

My question:
How to delete only the very last comma?

Comment: Why don't you try printing the comma __before__ the second and subsequent values printed?

Comment: *if (num != 1) cout << ',';* at the beginning of the *for, and no output of  ',' elsewhere

Comment: also flush the output with *cout << endl;*  after the *for*

Comment: Note that you are missing closing "}" parentheses in the result function. Also, you should add them in your else statement if you want both commands to be part of it.

Comment: BTW you ask for "*How to delete comma**s** at the end*", so you want to remove not only the very final comma but several, what do you **exactly** expect ?

Comment: @bruno still error sir. can y post the right one

Comment: @BusBaru yes edit your question to put the expected output

Comment: @bruno. i just wanna delete only the very last comma.

Comment: So you want to remove the last comma. Think about this, what will the values of `num` and `test` be when you are outputting the last comma? How can you use this fact to adjust the code so that it's doesn't output the last comma? This is a one line change to your code, I'm sure you can work it out.

Comment: @BusBaru so you already have your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a condition for the last value of `num`. The full code would be:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

void result(int test) 
{   

    for (int num = 1; num <= test; num++) 
    {   
        if (num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0)
            cout << "extra";

        else if (num % 3 == 0 )
            cout << "love ";


        else if(num %5 == 0) 
            cout << "extraextra";   

        else 
            cout << num;

        if(num < test) cout << ","; // Here you add the condition
    }

    cout << endl; // Allows for flushing the output (Thanks @bruno)
}


int main() 
{  
    int test = 100; 
    result(test); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I think that adding the `if` inside the loop is not worthy, since you know that that condition will be false only for `num=test`.

Comment: @Eddymage It seems to me that your concern is less about the efficiency of this code and more about the criticism of your own :) Surely it doesn't deserve a downvote for being maybe marginally less efficient for extremely large datasets and computations (I doubt that's the case here)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I was too severe giving the DV, but unless you edit the answer I can not remove it. Sorry if you feel a harsh criticism, it was not my intent. I think that this approach encourage writing less efficient code when you have to deal with more complicated problems (e.g. consider the case in which the ìf`check involves some FFTs of large dataset). Here you know in advance that the condition will be false only at the end of the cycle, so I do not see the point to check it at each step. It is true that your solution produces an elegant code, but I think that it is not efficient.

Comment: @Eddymage Regarding the DV - its your choice, I wanted a reason and got one, thanks! Coming to the code - OP had a specific, trivial issue and I provided a trivial, specific solution. They did not want a program for NASA to launch Apollo 21 into space, or write fourier transforms for large datasets (if that were the case, we would write much more efficient code and there would be more improvements than you can  think of right now) *this approach encourage writing less efficient code*, I disagree, a good programmer will write code to suit the situation. Premature optimization is not necessary.

Comment: @bruno I would also like to know your thoughts on this, seeing as you have much more experience than either of us

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava The loss of time introduced by the test is almost nothing,  since years the processors prepare the execution of both the two cases (test true / test false) so the execution pipe is not broken. Clearly the worst solution is to duplicate the code out of the  *for*  for the last turn like it is the case in the current answer of Eddymage, and not only because that code runs wrong when *result* is called with an argument <= 0, that way must **not** be used.

Comment: @bruno, you are totally right: repeated code is not good practice. I modified my answer, taking into consideration also the 0 input. Thanks for the suggestions and the patience!

Answer (score 2):

In case you really do not like the additional test of *num* visible in

```
for (int num = 1; num <= test; num++) 
{   
    if (num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0)
        cout << "extra";
    else if (num % 3 == 0 )
        cout << "love ";
    else if(num %5 == 0) 
        cout << "extraextra";   
    else 
        cout << num;

    if (num < test)
      cout << ',';
}
```

and

```
for (int num = 1; num <= test; num++) 
{   
    if (num != 1) 
      cout << ',';

    if (num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0)
        cout << "extra";
    else if (num % 3 == 0 )
        cout << "love ";
    else if(num %5 == 0) 
        cout << "extraextra";   
    else 
        cout << num;
}
```

you can avoid that explicit test doing :

```
const char * sep = "";

for (int num = 1; num <= test; num++) 
{   
    cout << sep;
    sep = ",";

    if (num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0)
        cout << "extra";
    else if (num % 3 == 0 )
        cout << "love ";
    else if(num %5 == 0) 
        cout << "extraextra";   
    else 
        cout << num;
}
```

but probably this is less readable and a (very) little more expensive at the execution

Answer (score 0):

After having read all the suggestion and the constructive critics, I modified my answer in the following way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void singlecheck(int num){

 if (num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0)
            cout << "extra";

        else if (num % 3 == 0 )
            cout << "love ";


        else if(num %5 == 0) 
            cout << "extraextra";   

        else 
            cout << num;
}

void result(int test)
{   
    if(test>0){
        for (int num = 1; num <test; num++){
            singlecheck(num);
            cout << ", ";
        }

    singlecheck(test);
    cout << endl;
    }


}

int main() 
{  
    int test = 15; 
    result(test); 

    return 0; 
}
```

I added one more function, which is doing the "test" job, while the cycle is done in another function. Now the result is correct also with input 0: I added one `if` at the beginning. In this way, only one `if`-check has to be done instead of a total of `test` `if`-checks, which was my principal concern. Previous version has repeated code which is not a good programming practice.

Comment: @Eddymage can we make a shortone ?. this is works but so long code

Comment: @Bus Bari, you can rely to Anurag's answer that it has shorter code,  but you are adding one more `if` at each iteration of your cycle, while my strategy has no more computational cost. For small numbers there are no difference, but maybe for larger ones there could be an appreciable difference in time.

Comment: @Eddymage you duplicate all the function body, this is not readable, and if a change has to be done you will have to do it 2 times. Furthermore if the call is *result(0)* you do not produce the expected output

Comment: @Bruno, right, for 0 input it should be added a test in the second part. But what if the test `if (num<test)` instead of being so simple and cheap involves a more costly computation (e.g. function involving FFTs of images)? The computational cost will.be very high. By the way, there are some ways to shorten the above code, I'll write the modifications as soon as I reach my pc!

Comment: @Eddymage doing that you will have something similar to the other answers, it is also possible to have no test nor duplication of the for body but that do not change a lot

Comment: @Eddymage you said your goal is to be more efficient, do you think to call a function is more efficient than to compare 2 local variables ?

Comment: @bruno ...and you have another good point. I thought about not repeating code, but it is true that in this case the comparison is more efficient, calling `test` times a function is too expensive. I will delete my answer soon since it completely fails in providing a good alternative.

Comment: Its still a good solution. Don't delete it, its another way of achieving the result and might help someone else in a similar scenario

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava thanks again for the comments and the patience.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop runs for the last time at `num == test`, so just print commas for num less than test or num not equal to test.

i.e. simply replace `cout << ",";` with:

```cpp
if(num < test) cout << ",";
```

or

```cpp
if(num != test) cout << ",";
```