# What to do so that it does not print after my last number (,)?

Tags: c++

Given two numbers, output the prime numbers between them and separate these numbers with a comma, and don't print the comma at the end of the output.

What can I do so that it does not print the comma after my last number?
I do not want to change this code much

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a,b,sum=0,x,aaa=0,primeman; 
    cin>>a;
    cin>>b;
    for (int i=a+1; i <b ;i++){
        sum+=1;
        x=0;
        for(int j=1;j<i/2;j++){
            if (i%j==0){
                x++;
            }
        }   
        if (x==1){
            cout<<i<<",";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not hard. Instead of printing a comma after each number, print a comma before each number. Now think how you can adjust that code to avoid printing a comma before the first number. Problem solved.

Comment: It seems that this question a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61224228/how-do-i-remove-comma-after-last-number-output-loop-in-c/61224415#61224415

Comment: My friend, this is a CS1 "do my homework" question.  I would suggest using your critical thinking skills to figure it out.  A pro programmer will get a question like this about 20 times a day (imo).  With that said, the answer is to print a leading comma for all but the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following approach:

```
std::string delimiter("");
if (x==1) {
    std::cout << delimiter << i;
    delimiter = ",";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For avoiding comma to be printed after the last number, we can print it before each number except the first one. To do this, we introduce a new boolean variable **firstElement** which will ensure that comma is not printed before the first element in our output.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a,b,x; 
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    bool firstElement= true; // marker for the first element
    for (int i=a+1; i<b; i++){
        x=0;
        for(int j=2;j<=sqrt(i);j++){ // replaced "division by 2" by square root 
            if (i%j==0){
                x++;
                break; // once a number is found to be divisible by other, it is 
                       // not a prime, hence no need to check further
            }
        }   
        if(x==0){
            if(firstElement){ // if 'i' is the first element(prime number)
                cout << i;
                firstElement = false;

            }
            else{
                cout << ", " << i ;
            }
            
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I have removed some unused variables like sum, aaa, primeman, please see whether it is still required for some other purpose.